# Get the interior measurements of winform

Tags: c#, winforms, location

I'm trying to position a button on my Form so that it's in the very lower right hand corner of my form. The button is 150 by 100, and so I have

`button1.Location = new Point(this.Width - 150, this.Height - 100);`

After some testing, I find that this is about 15 pixels too far right, and almost 45 pixels too far down. I believe (although I'm not sure) this is because `this.Width` and `this.Height` include the border of the form where the form name and minimize/maximize/close buttons go.

Is there a way to measure just the inside of the form so that I can use something like `button1.Location = new Point(insideWidth - 150, insideHeight - 100);`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `ClientSize.Width` and `ClientSize.Height` instead.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks! That works perfectly! (If you make it an answer I'll accept)

Comment: You are welcome, glad that helped. Also thanks for the kindly proposal, but I don't think I will, most likely it's a duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwinforms%5D+form+clientsize